# JQGrid: Add,Edit form not showing on pager button click

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using JQuery 2.0.3 with jquery-migrate-1.4.1.
After adding JQuery migrate js, JQGrid add, edit pager button not displaying add/edit form on pager button click.

I can not Downgrade JQuery as I am using bootstrap multi-select drop down button in my page which requires Jquery 1.9 and above.

How can I make JQGrid pager button to work. Plz. suggest.

FIND MY CODE BELOW:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="org.samsung.network.util.Constants" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@page import="javax.sql.DataSource" %>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext" %>
<%@page import="javax.naming.Context" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Test</title>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/NSTest_Dev/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/NSTest_Dev/css/bootstrap-3.2.0-min.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/NSTest_Dev/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/NSTest_Dev/css/common.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/NSTest_Dev/css/demos_m.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/NSTest_Dev/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/NSTest_Dev/js/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/NSTest_Dev/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/NSTest_Dev/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/NSTest_Dev/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/NSTest_Dev/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/NSTest_Dev/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    <%if(session.getAttribute("FromDevID") != null && session.getAttribute("ToDevID") != null ){%>
    $('#from').val('<%=(String)session.getAttribute("FromDevID")%>');
    $('#to').val('<%=(String)session.getAttribute("ToDevID")%>');
    $('#sec').val('search');
 <%}%>

$('#jqg_calltest').jqGrid('GridUnload'); 
$("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid({
    //url from wich data should be requested
    url: 'calltest_json.jsp',
    postData: {
        fromDate: function() { return jQuery("#from").val(); },
        toDate: function() { return jQuery("#to").val(); },
        section : function() { return jQuery("#sec").val(); },
        sItem : function() { return jQuery('#sItem :selected').val();},
        sItemTxt : function() { return jQuery("#sItemTxt").val(); },
        locationid : function() { return jQuery("#sLocation").val(); },
        testgroupid : function() { return jQuery("#sTestGroup").val(); },
    },
    //type of data
    datatype: 'json',
    //url access method type
    mtype: 'POST',
    multiselect: true,
    //columns names
    colNames: ['Device ID', 'IMEI','Call Action','Phone Number', 'Calling To','Receiving From','Granularity','Periodicity','Mute Duration(in Mins)','Request Received','Device Status','Remarks', 'Location','Test Group','Restart', 'Stop'],
    //columns model
    colModel: [
                { name: 'devid', index: 'devid', align: 'center', width: 60, editable: true, sortable: false },
                { name: 'imei', index: 'imei', align: 'center', width: 120, sortable: false, editable: true},
                { name: 'call_action', index: 'call_action', align: 'center', width: 70, sortable: false, editable: true },
                { name: 'phone_number', index: 'phone_number', align: 'center', width: 100, sortable: false, editable: true },
                { name: 'call_number', index: 'call_number', align: 'center', width: 100, sortable: false, editable: true },
                { name: 'call_receive', index: 'call_receive', align: 'center', width: 100, sortable: false, editable: true },
                { name: 'granularity', index: 'granularity', align: 'center', width: 65, sortable: false, editable: true },
                { name: 'periodicity', index: 'periodicity', align: 'center', width: 65, sortable: false, editable: true },
                { name: 'duration', index: 'duration', align: 'center', width: 65, sortable: false, editable: true },
                { name: 'gcmstatus', index: 'gcmstatus', align: 'center', width: 80, sortable: false, editable: false,formatter: gcmStatusFormatter},
                { name: 'dstatus', index: 'dstatus', align: 'center', width: 90, sortable: false, editable: false,formatter: deviceStatusFormatter},
                { name: 'remarks', index: 'remarks', align: 'center', width: 230, sortable: false, editable: false, formatter: remarksFormatter},
                { name: 'LID', index: 'LID', align: 'center', width: 80, sortable: false, editable: false, formatter: remarksFormatter},
                { name: 'TGID', index: 'TGID', align: 'center', width: 80, sortable: false, editable: false, formatter: remarksFormatter},
                { name: 'restart', index: 'restart', align: 'center', width: 80, sortable: false, editable: false, formatter: restartBtnFormatter },
                { name: 'stop', index: 'stop', align: 'center', width: 80, sortable: false, editable: false, formatter: stopBtnFormatter }


    ],

    //pager for grid
    pager: $('#jqg_calltestpager'),

    //number of rows per page
    rowNum: 100,
    rowList: [10,25,40,75,100, 500, 1000, 1500],
    sortname: 'DeviceID',
    sortorder: 'ASC',
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: false,
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 40,
    height: 600,
    //width: 1200,
    caption: "&nbsp;&nbsp;Call Test Data",
    emptyrecords: 'No data to display!',
    loadtext: 'Loading...',
  //  autoid : true,

    afterInsertRow: function (rowid, data) {
        // To Restart Row Test
         var  grid = $("#jqg_calltest");
         var iCol = getColumnIndexByName (grid, "restart");
         $("td:eq("+iCol+")","#"+rowid).click(function () {
         //$("td:eq(10)","#"+rowid).click(function () {
            var strdata ="";
            var rowData =jQuery('#jqg_calltest').jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);

            strdata = strdata +rowData.devid+"&";
            strdata = strdata + rowData.imei+"&";
            strdata = strdata +rowData.call_action+"&";
            strdata = strdata + rowData.call_number+"&";
            strdata = strdata + rowData.call_receive+"&";
            strdata = strdata + ",";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SendCallMessage",
                dataType:"json",
                data:{
                    calldata: strdata
                },
                success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    // display an success message if needed
                    alert("Call Test for Device ID: "+rowData.devid +" has been Restarted");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // display an error message in any way
                    alert("ERROR Restarting Call Test!!!");
                }
            });
         });

        //To Stop Row Test
         iCol = getColumnIndexByName (grid, "stop");
         $("td:eq("+iCol+")","#"+rowid).click(function () {
        //$("td:eq(11)","#"+rowid).click(function () {
            var strdata ="";
            var rowData =jQuery('#jqg_calltest').jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
                    strdata = strdata +rowData.devid+"&";
            strdata = strdata + rowData.imei;
            strdata = strdata + ",";
            //alert(strdata);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SendStopCallMessage",
                dataType:"json",
                data:{
                    stoppingdata: strdata
                },

                success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    // display an success message if needed
                    alert("Call Test for Device ID: "+rowData.devid +" has been stopped");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // display an error message in any way
                    alert("ERROR Stopping Call Test!!!");
                }
            });
         }); 
    },
    loadComplete : function(){
        var selRowIds = jQuery("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
        totalcount = 0;
        failcount = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<selRowIds.length;i++){ 
            totalcount++;
            var celValue = jQuery("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid ('getCell', selRowIds[i], 'dstatus');
            if(celValue.indexOf("DISCONNECTED")>=0){
                 failcount++;
             }
        }
         $("label[for='lblCount']").text(failcount + '/' + totalcount);
         $("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid("setLabel", "rn", "RN");
 },
  onSelectRow: function (id, status) {
     // var selRowId = jQuery("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
      var celValue = jQuery("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid ('getCell', id, 'dstatus');
      if (status) { // selected
             if(celValue.indexOf("FAIL")>=0){
                  failcount++;
              }
            totalcount ++;
        }else{
             if(celValue.indexOf("FAIL")>=0){
                  failcount--;
              }
            totalcount --;  
        }
        $("label[for='lblCount']").text(failcount + '/' + totalcount);
    },
    onSelectAll:function(id,status){
        if(status){
            totalcount = id.length;
            failcount = 0;
            for(i=0;i<id.length;i++){
                var celValue = jQuery("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid ('getCell', id[i], 'dstatus');
                 if(celValue.indexOf("FAIL")>=0){
                     failcount++;
                 }
            }
        }else{
            totalcount = 0;
            failcount = 0;
        }

        $("label[for='lblCount']").text(failcount + '/' + totalcount);
    }
  });
jQuery("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqg_calltestpager', {
    edit : true, add : true, del : true,search : false, refresh:false, refreshstate: "current"},
    //edit options
    {
          beforeShowForm: function(form) {
             $('#tr_imei', form).hide(); 
             $('#tr_devid', form).hide(); 
            //$('#tr_imei', formid).attr("disabled", "disabled");
         }, 


         afterSubmit: function (response) {
               if (response.status == 200) {
                   $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', 
                    { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{current:true}]);//Reloads the grid after edit
                  //failcount = 0;
                  //totalcount = 0;
                   return [true, ''];
               }
                else {
                   $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', 
                   { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{current:true}]); //Reloads the grid after edit
                  //failcount = 0;
                  //totalcount = 0;
                   return [false, response.responseText];
                   //Captures and displays the response text on th Edit window
               } 

           },

         onclickSubmit: function(rp_ge, postdata) {
                    rp_ge.url = 'calltest_json.jsp?section=edit';
            },

           closeOnEscape: true,//Closes the popup on pressing escape key
           reloadAfterEdit: true,
           closeAfterEdit: true,
           drag: true,
    },
    //add options
     {
        afterShowForm: function (form) {
         $('#tr_imei', form).show(); 
         $('#tr_devid', form).show(); 
         }, 
          afterSubmit: function (response) {
            var myInfo = '<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">'+
                         '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" ' +
                             'style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>' +
                         response.responseText +
                         '</div>',
                $infoTr = $("#TblGrid_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + ">tbody>tr.tinfo"),
                $infoTd = $infoTr.children("td.topinfo");
            $infoTd.html(myInfo);
            $infoTr.show();

            // display status message to 3 sec only
            setTimeout(function () {
                $infoTr.slideUp("slow");
            }, 5000);
            //failcount = 0;
            //totalcount = 0;
            return [true, "", ""]; // response should be interpreted as successful
        }, 
       errorTextFormat: function (response) {
           var txt = response.statusText;
           var restxt = response.responseText;
            if(response.status == 406){
            return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" ' +
                         'style="float:left; margin-right:.3em;"></span>' +
                         "Device ID Already Exists";
            }
            else {
            return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" ' +
             'style="float:left; margin-right:.3em;"></span>' +
             "IMEI Already Exists";
            }

        }, 

        onclickSubmit: function(rp_ge, postdata) {
            var totalrecords = $('#jqg_calltest').getGridParam("records") ;

            rp_ge.url = 'calltest_json.jsp?section=add&devidmax='+ totalrecords;    
        },
        closeOnEscape: true,//Closes the popup on pressing escape key
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        closeAfterSubmit: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        drag: true,
    },
    //del options
    {

         beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
            var rowids = jQuery('#jqg_calltest').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');


            $("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html("Delete selected Record with Device ID<b>: " +
                    rowids + "</b>?");

        },
        afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
               if (response.status == 200) {
                   $('#jqg_calltest').jqGrid('setGridParam', 
                     { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{current:true}]);//Reloads the grid after edit
                 //failcount = 0;
                // totalcount = 0;
                   return [true, ''];
               }
               else {
                   $('#jqg_calltest').jqGrid('setGridParam', 
                     { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{current:true}]); //Reloads the grid after edit
                 // failcount = 0;
                 //totalcount = 0;
                   return [false, response.responseText];
                   //Captures and displays the response text on th Edit window
               }
            }, 
        onclickSubmit: function(rp_ge, postdata) {

             var selIds = jQuery("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
             var strdata ='';
             for(var i = 0; i < selIds.length; i++){
                var rowData =jQuery("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid("getRowData", selIds[i]);

                 strdata = strdata + rowData.imei; 
                 strdata = strdata + ",";
             }  
            rp_ge.url = 'calltest_json.jsp?section=delete&imei='+ strdata;
        },
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterDelete: true,
        reloadAfterDelete: true, 
     },
    //search options
    {
    },
    // veiw options
    {
        width: 500, height: 'auto',
        closeOnEscape: true
    });
  });

var failcount = 0;     
var totalcount = 0;

   function restartBtnFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {    
     return "<input type='button' value='Restart' class='btn btn-primary'/>";
  }

  function stopBtnFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {    
    return "<input type='button' value='Stop' class='btn btn-primary'/>";
  }

   function gcmStatusFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {  
       if(cellvalue == "YES")
          return '<span style="color:green"><B>'+cellvalue+'</B></span>';
       else  if(cellvalue == "NA")
         return '<span style="color:blue"><B>'+cellvalue+'</B></span>';
      else
        return '<span style="color:red"><B>'+cellvalue+'<B></span>';
 }

  function deviceStatusFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) { 
    if(cellvalue == "CONNECTED")
           return '<span style="color:green"><B>'+cellvalue+'</B></span>';
    else  if(cellvalue == "NA")
       return '<span style="color:blue"><B>'+cellvalue+'</B></span>';
   else
   {
      return '<span style="color:red"><B>'+cellvalue+'<B></span>';
   }
 }

 function remarksFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {  
      return '<B>'+cellvalue+'<B>';
 }

 $(function(){
     getColumnIndexByName = function (grid, columnName) {
         var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = cm.length;
         for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
             if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                 return i; // return the index
             }
         }
         return -1;
     }
});





   function clearResults() {
        //debugger;
        //failcount = 0;
        //totalcount = 0;
          $('form').submit(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
          });

          var selIds = jQuery("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
          if (selIds.length <= 0) {
              alert("Please select atleast one row!!!!");
              return;
           } 
          else{
             var strdata ='';
             var strclearCols = '';
               for(var i = 0; i < selIds.length; i++){
                var rowData =jQuery("#jqg_calltest").jqGrid("getRowData", selIds[i]);

                   strdata = strdata +rowData.devid+"&";
                   strdata = strdata + rowData.imei+"&";
                   strdata = strdata + "calltest"+"&";
                   strdata = strdata + ",";
               }
               var clearClomns  = $('#clearRes').val();
              // alert(clearClomns);
               if(clearClomns == null){
                   alert("Please select at least one item from clear results dropdown!!!!");
                   return;
               }else{
                   for(var i = 0; i < clearClomns.length; i++){
                       strclearCols = strclearCols + clearClomns[i]+",";
                   }
               }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ClearResults",
                dataType:"json",
                data:{
                    clearRemarksData: strdata,
                    clearFieldsData : strclearCols
                },

                success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    // display an success message if needed
                    alert("Cleared Results Successfully");
                    //$("#clearRes").multiselect('refresh');
                    $("#clearRes option:selected").prop("selected", false);
                    $("#clearRes").multiselect('refresh');
                    $('#jqg_calltest').jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype : 'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{current:true}]);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // display an error message in any way
                    alert("ERROR Clearing Results!!!!");
                    $('#jqg_calltest').jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype : 'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{current:true}]);
                }
            });
          }
       };



$(function () {

    $('#clearRes').multiselect({ 
         includeSelectAllOption: true,
         // enableFiltering:true,
         // buttonClass: 'btn btn-default',
         nonSelectedText: 'Clear Results',
         /*  templates: {
             button: '<span class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" data-toggle="dropdown">Clear Results</span>'
         }  */

      });

    }); 

    </script>
  </head>
<body>

<table id="jqg_calltest">
      <tr>
           <td />
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="jqg_calltestpager"></div>
    <br/>

    <select id="clearRes" multiple="multiple" >
        <option value="ReceivedGCMStatus">Clear Request Recvd.</option>
        <option value="DeviceStatus">Clear Device Status</option>
        <option value="Remarks">Clear Remarks</option>
    </select>

       <input type="submit" value="Clear" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="clearResults()"/>
      <input type="hidden" value="overview" id="sec"/>

     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Could you include the JavaScript code which you use to create jqGrid or provide the URL to the demo which reproduces the problem. I develop free jqGrid fork and I'm sure that it works with jQuery 2.0.3 and with jquery-migrate-1.4.1. It works with jQuery 3.0 too. jqGrid don't require jquery-migrate, but the including of it don't provide any problems too.

Comment: @Oleg, I am using jqGrid  4.2.0 - jQuery Grid.

Comment: The version 4.2.0 is more as 4.5 years old. It's dead since very long time. Many parts of your existing code are unclear. I'd recommend you to try free jqGrid 4.13.3, which you can use from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). You need just modify URLs to three jqGrid file: `ui.jqgrid.css`, `grid.locale-en.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. Moreover I'd recommend you to add Font Awesome CSS and to add `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` and `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` options of jqGrid: free jqGrid contains native support of Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Oleg... I m becoming a FAN of yours... :)

Comment: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-bootstrap.htm) as an example of usage Bootstrap and free jqGrid. [The wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki), readmes to every version (see the reference at the end of [the latest readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md)), which was published and [the short document](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) provides some documentation about new features, which I implemented. I use 4.x.y as version, because I try to hold compatibility with old version